# Can i change and int value inside a task while its running? c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, int, task

I currently am learning how to use Tasks in c#, i want to be able to run 2 tasks at the same time. then when the first task ends. tell the code to stop the second one. I have tried many things but none have worked, i have tried:

1. Try looking for something related to task.stop and have not found it. i am using task.wait for the first task so when the first one ends i have to do something to stop the second one.
2. Since the second one is infinite (its an eternal loop) i tried making the parameter of the loop something i could change in the main code, but its like the task is a method and variables in them are unique.

TL;DR: I want to know if i can change a parameter inside a task in order to stop it from outside its code. do the task itself take any parameters? and can i change them in the main code after they start running?

If none of the previous things are possible is it then possible in any way to stop an infinite task?

CODE:

```
Task a = new Task(() =>
{
    int sd = 3; 
    while (sd < 20)
    {
        Console.Write("peanuts");
        sd++; //this i can change cuz its like local to the task

    }
});
a.Start();
// infinite task
Task b = new Task(() => 
{
    int s = 3; // parameter i want to change to stop it
    while (s < 10)
    {
        Console.Write(s+1);

    }
});
b.Start();
a.Wait();
// Now here I want to stop task b

Console.WriteLine("peanuts");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void Run()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task1(cts);
    Task2(cts.Token);
}

private static void Task2(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        int s = 3; // parameter i want to change to stop it

                    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.Write(s + 1);
        }
    }, token);
}

private static void Task1(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        int sd = 3;

        while (sd < 20)
        {
            Console.Write("peanuts");
            sd++; //this i can change cuz its like local to the task
        }
    }).ContinueWith(t => cts.Cancel());
}
```

`CancellationTokenSource` will be cancelled when *Task1* is finished. So, *Task2* checks cancellation token each iteration and exits infinite loop when cancellation is requested.